# How do you loop but make the value back to 0 the variable d1 is stacking the input making the average double the amount?

Tags: java, nested, do-while

```
   do{
    do{
      System.out.print("Enter number" + count + ":");
        if(scan.hasNextInt()){
        d1 = scan.nextInt();
        count ++;
          }
        else{
            System.out.print("Number is invalid. ");
            scan.next();
            continue;
               
           }
         t+=d1;
      
       }while(count<=5);
   
       total = t / 5;
       
       System.out.print("The average is :" + total + " ." );
       
       System.out.print(" [do you want to continue press[ y ]for yes and [ n]  for no ]:");
```

I tried placing the t+= inside and outside of the brackets but no good still the same result
this part is where I am confused because the t+=d1 will stack the more I loop e.g. all my 5 numbers is 25 then avg is 25 then I press y then loops back I enter same 5 of 25 then the avg is 50

Answer (score 0):

Recommendation:

- If you want a faster answer, share a runnable code.
- ALWAYS indent your code, it will be easier to read.
- The name of the variables are so important, so please, give them an appropriate name to know what they contain. (For example, you declared a variable "total" which will contain the average result, it will be reasonable to call it "avg" or "average")

this is a test class:

```
class StackOverflowTest {

    // regex pattern
    private static final String REGEX_Y_OR_N = "^[yn]$";
    
    @Test
    void execute() {
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String needToContinue = "x";
        
        // loop until the user press "n"
        do {
            
            // for each iteration, tot and count will be reinitialized
            int tot = 0;
            int count = 0;
            
            // loop until the user enter 5 numbers
            do {
                
                System.out.print("Enter a number : ");
                
                int input;
                if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                    input = scan.nextInt();
                    count++;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Number is invalid."+"\n");
                    scan.next();
                    continue;
                }
                
                tot += input;

            } while (count < 5);

            double avg = tot / 5;

            System.out.println("The average is : " + avg + " .");

            System.out.println("\n"+" [do you want to continue press [ y ] for yes and [ n ] for no ]: ");
            
            // loop until a valid character is entered ("y" or "n")
            do {
                
                needToContinue = scan.next();
                
                if (!needToContinue.matches(REGEX_Y_OR_N)) {
                    System.out.println("\n"+"Invalid character!"+"\n");
                    System.out.println(" [do you want to continue press [ y ] for yes and [ n ] for no ]: ");
                }
                
            } while (!needToContinue.matches(REGEX_Y_OR_N)); 
            

        } while (needToContinue.contains("y"));
        
        scan.close();
    }
    
}
```